# Custom parameter injection with ParamConverterProvider does not work properly

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I am trying to have a custom parameter annotation that I inject as parameter to my endpoint. It is supposed to be a role in keycloak and looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface KeycloakRole {
    String realm();
    String role();
}
```

I have a converter class:

```
public class KeycloakRoleConverter implements ParamConverter<Set<String>> {
    private final Set<String> userRoles;
    public KeycloakRoleConverter(Set<String> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> fromString(String value) {
        if (!userRoles.contains(value)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("User does not have required role");
        }
        return Set.of(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Set<String> value) {
        return value.iterator().next();
    }
}
```

with a converter provider class:

```
@RequestScoped
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class KeycloakRoleResolver implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Context
    SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        LOG.infof("getConverter has been called");
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation.annotationType() == KeycloakRole.class) {
                KeycloakRole keycloakRole = (KeycloakRole) annotation;
                Set<String> userRoles = getUserRoles(keycloakRole.realm());
                return (ParamConverter<T>) new KeycloakRoleConverter(userRoles);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Set<String> getUserRoles(String realm) {
        KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext) securityContext;
        AccessToken token = keycloakSecurityContext.getToken();
        if (token == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to obtain user roles");
        }

        Map<String, Object> otherClaims = token.getOtherClaims();
        JsonArray resourceAccessArray = (JsonArray) otherClaims.get("resource_access");
        JsonObject resourceAccess = resourceAccessArray.getJsonObject(0);
        JsonObject profilerCore = resourceAccess.getJsonObject("profiler-core");
        JsonArray rolesArray = profilerCore.getJsonArray("roles");

        Set<String> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rolesArray.size(); i++) {
            userRoles.add(rolesArray.getString(i));
        }

        return userRoles;
    }
```

my endpoint:

```
@Path("/api/profile")
@Authenticated
@ApplicationScoped
public class AdminResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/custom-role-ep")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Collection<String> customEp(@KeycloakRole(realm = "profiler", role = "view-all") Set<String> userRoles) {
        LOG.info("User roles: " + userRoles);
        return userRoles;
    }
}
```

I am using postman with a keycloak access token and would like to output the roles for the user.

I am using this in a quarkus application. For some reason the userRoles outputs always null. Weird thing is my getConverter method does not seem to run at all because I don't see the log in my terminal.

Thanks for the input and help,
Ayume

Comment: Do you have a sample application somewhere we can try?

Comment: sure thing!
[github repo](https://github.com/Phq-art/custom-param-quarkus-test)

Maybe the method header of the endpoint is faulty but the general propblem I see is that getConverter() does not run.
I would be happy with another approach as well. Bit of an influence was Springs [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/kdoc-api/spring-framework/org.springframework.web.method.support/-handler-method-argument-resolver/)

Comment: @geoand I also just stumbled apon an [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26152) where it was said that the **ContextResolver** is not really advised to use. Do you think an Object Mapper could fit my needs?
Sorry that the code I provided is a bit messy. It's mostly really about some custom annotation that I want to pass as param to an endpoint (in our case calling it using postman and trying to output the roles that are stored in a Set of Strings)

Comment: I am not clear about what the end goal is. Are you trying to read an HTTP body or something else?

Comment: just handling data before it reaches the EP. Aforementioned [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/kdoc-api/spring-framework/org.springframework.web.method.support/-handler-method-argument-resolver/) is a spring way to do it. 
Here I found a **Custom context provider** [demo github repo](https://github.com/dnebing/custom-context-provider)
In my case, whatever works best with Quarkus, I want to register some kind of method that runs before data reaches the endpoint and this one gets a set of strings with roles from the keycloak access token.